# Wrong logical/physical sector size can lead to file corruption?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I'm experiencing continuous file corruption problems so I have to run `fsck` almost every time I start Ubuntu 16.04. :( :( :(

Recently, I bought a second new 1TB hard disk and reinstalled everything. After few days the problem was again there... the system boots but is not usable (today I've got a lot of folders mounted in read-only mode...)

I've made all the checks trying to detect an hardware problem (memtest, prime95, Gsmartcontrol, BIOS upgrade, etc) but I didn't find any fault. Also the temperature of the CPU is quite stable.

Could the adopted partitioning be the problem?

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x583cc96a

Device     Boot    Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048    7999487    7997440   3,8G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda2        8001534 1953523711 1945522178 927,7G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5        8001536   47060991   39059456  18,6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       47063040 1953523711 1906460672 909,1G 83 Linux

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

I read that a misaligned logical/physical sector size can only impact 
the performance. Nevertheless I read also some case of PCs not booting at all. Which is true?
Should I not waste further time and buy a new PC? :( :( :(

Comment: No, the `Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary` warning is harmless for an extended partition type; ignore it. My guess is you've got a bad cable, flaky disk controller hardware on the motherboard, or some other hardware problem. Another possibility is that you're not shutting down properly; you should *always* use a proper shutdown command, not just hit the computer's power button.

Comment: @RodSmith - Hi Rod. I've checked visually the motherboard (ASRock N68-GS4 FX) and I didn't find any problem. I will do a double check now.
I always shutdown the machine by using the proper command on the Ubuntu main menu.

Comment: A visual check most likely won't detect a voltage fluctuation, microscopic fracture of a critical trace, failing chip, etc. It might or might not detect a poorly-seated connector, failing cable etc.

Comment: @RodSmith - yeah, you're right.
Now I've got the root partition in read-only mode... great day is today for me! There should be an error on boot record (fsck skips the root partition as a zero-length one).
I've no other choice than buying a new PC, even if it is not an happy period for me from an economical point of view... :( :( :(